# "None of [Index(['Length_EE', 'Length_Trj'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Tags: python, matplotlib, indexing, boxplot

I'm trying to create boxplots for my dataset and the code I use is write below:

```
dataset.to_csv("H.csv", index=False)
dataset = pd.read_csv("/H.csv", delimiter=";", dtype='object', na_values='.')

print(dataset.columns)

dataset[["Posture","Length_EE","Length_Trj"]]

Length_data = dataset.groupby('Posture')
Length_data.boxplot(column=['Length_EE', 'Length_Trj'])
plt.show()
```

as you can see in the code with "print (dataset.columns)" I have tried above all to understand if in the file the names of the columns etc. were in their place ... but everything is ok ... I can't understand what the problem is .
Is there someone who can help me? Thanks so much!

Comment: I think only `dataset["Posture","Length_EE","Length_Trj"]` would be fine. Could you try that and let me know?

Comment: Hi! I try it but it doesn't work... :(